# Unterschied zw "verkünden" und "ausrufen"?

Tags: standard-german, low-german, difference

Es geht um die Wörter *verkünden* und *ausrufen*, also um Situationen, bei denen man etwas anderen meldet. Ich benutze normalerweise das Wort *melden*, aber es wäre toll, auch andere Wörter benutzen zu lernen. Unklar ist mir das Wort *ausrufen*, weil ich nie gehört hab, wie man es benutzt, oder mir es einfach nicht gemerkt habe.
Ich hätte gern einen Tipp, um schnell merken zu können, wie und wo man die beiden Worte benutzt. Auch die Geschichte der Entstehung würde mir helfen. Alles, damit diese Wörter richtig in meinem Kopf liegen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es gibt einige klar unterscheidbare Bedeutungen von *ausrufen* und *verkünden*, aber auch einen Bereich, in dem beide Verben semantisch überlappen. Die Unterschiede lassen sich meines Erachtens gut aus zweisprachigen Wörterbüchern erkennen und die Frage handelt ja auch nur von dem Bereich, in dem der Sinn beider Worte übereinstimmt. Deshalb beziehe ich mich nur auf das semantische Feld "kundtun, mitteilen, melden" (englisch *to proclaim, to announce*, lateinisch *PROCLAMARE*). In meinen Augen gibt es folgende Abgrenzungen:

### Einen Notstand *ausrufen*

*ausrufen* wird in der festen Redewedung *einen Notstand ausrufen* verwendet, bzw. in analogen Formulierungen, in denen eine staatliche Stelle einen besonderen Zustand deklariert. Die Äußerung hat damit nicht nur mitteilenden, sondern auch deklarierenden Charakter. Es handelt sich also nicht nur um eine beschreibende Äußerung eines Zustands, sondern um einen [illokutiven Akt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illokution%C3%A4rer_Akt), also um eine Sprechhandlung, die den Zustand nicht lediglich beschreibt, sondern *herstellt*:

> Immer mehr Orte in Deutschland haben bereits den Klimanotstand ausgerufen, zuletzt München.

> Am Mittwoch wird wieder der Katastrophenfall ausgerufen.

Die folgenden Sätze wären auch möglich:

> Immer mehr Orte in Deutschland haben bereits den Klimanotstand verkündet, zuletzt München.

> Am Mittwoch wird wieder der Katastrophenfall verkündet.

Damit würde aber nicht gesagt, dass es sich um einen illokutiven Akt handelt.

### Mit Dativ-Objekt

*verkünden* kann mit einem Dativ-Objekt stehen, dem Addressaten der Botschaft. *ausrufen* kann nicht mit einem solchen Objekt stehen:

> Ich verkünde euch <sup>[Dativ-Objekt]</sup> große Freude.

> <strike>Ich rufe Euch große Freude aus.</strike>

### (Impliziter) Bezug zum Addressaten der Rede

In anderen sprachlichen Äußerungen markiert *verkünden* eine bestimmte Haltung des Sprechers und eine bestimmte Beziehung zum Addressaten. In jedem Fall hat *verkünden* einen Addressaten, auch wenn dieser nicht explizit erwähnt wird. Darüber hinaus hat etwas, das *verkündet* wird, in der Regel Neuigkeitscharakter. *ausrufen* hingegen setzt nicht, auch nicht implzit, voraus, dass es einen Adressaten gibt. Einen *Ausruf* kann man also auch tätigen, wenn man allein ist, *verkünden* kann man nicht, wenn man allein ist.

### Art und Weise des Sprechens

*ausrufen* markiert in der Regel mehr die Art und Weise der Äußerung - ein besonders lautes Sprechen mit erhobener Stimme (*rufen* heißt englisch *to shout*, lateinisch *VOCARE*, *CLAMARE*). Auch wenn *verkünden* aus praktischen Gründen oft ebenfalls mit lauter Stimme geschieht, ist das nicht notwendig im Wort *verkünden* enhalten, in *ausrufen* hingegen schon:

Der Satz

> Sie verkündete, jetzt ins Bett zu gehen.

betont eher, dass diese Tatsache den Addressaten neu war, und dass *sie* den Entschluss, *jetzt* ins Bett zu gehen, womöglich gerade erst getroffen hat. Das muss nicht besonders laut oder auffällig geschehen sein. Dahingegen sagt der Satz

> Sie rief aus, jetzt ins Bett zu gehen.

eindeutig, dass die Äußerung *gerufen* wurde.

Comment: Hey im "Ich verkünde Euch [Dativ-Objekt] große Freude". Warum ist Euch mit gross geschrieben? Soll es nicht "euch" sein, wenn du "ihr" im Dativ meinst, oder "Ihnen", wenn du das höfliche Sie im Dativ meinst?

Comment: @Capuccinolady Stimmt, _euch_ müsste klein geschrieben werden. Ich habe es geändert.